# Can I carry a Zink portable printer in carry-on baggage?

Tags: hand-luggage, electronic-items, prohibited-items

I have a Zink printer (Kodak Mini3 Retro). Can I carry it in my carry-on baggage? I am traveling with Singapore Airlines from India to Singapore and the Philippines.

Comment: Where from? This is probably more important than the destination.

Comment: I'm traveling from India to Singapore, with onward journey to Philippines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singapore Airlines lists the restrictions of battery powered devices on its website [here](https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/us/travel-info/baggage/baggage-restrictions/)

It states for:

> Watt-hours rating not exceeding 100Wh / Lithium content not exceeding
> 2g For example: Laptops, mobile phones, and digital and video cameras

That for devices with batteries in them in cabin baggage:

> In Equipment: Yes
>
> 1. Maximum of 15 devices per passenger (combined with checked baggage)

I haven't been able to find the battery size of the Photo printer you want to take, but for comparison, the latest iPhone 15 Pro Max has a battery of about 4400 mAh or 17 Wh.

I did find a user manual for a Kodak Step Instant Print digital camera which also uses the same Zink paper, and prints out a 2x3 inch picture (compared with the 3x3 for your printer).  This manual said that it has a 700 mAh battery, so 1/6 the size of the iPhone 15's battery.

So my gut feeling is that you should be safe taking this printer as cabin baggage.  But if you really wanted to be sure, take a look the manual you should have gotten with the printer and look for its battery size.  However, I would it expect it to be in the same order of size as to what the Step camera has.

Answer (score 3):

While each country has its own rules and details may vary, checking the US TSA [What can I bring?](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all) page often gives insights.

In this case, they explicitly state that printers and printer ink are allowed both in cabin and hold luggage, so there is little chance other agencies will think differently.

The list of items prohibited or with various restrictions for flights departing from India is [here](https://www.aai.aero/en/airports/security-info/kullu-manali) while that for Singapore is [here](https://www.caas.gov.sg/public-passengers/before-your-flight/pack-it-right-for-your-flight).

As pointed out by [Peter M](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/184914/30703) a possible reason would have been the battery, but it’s unlikely to exceed the limits for those.